# Docker-entrypoint.sh results in "not found" for ARM image with golang

Tags: docker, go, raspberry-pi, arm, raspbian

My problem is that I get an error when running my container on an ARM arch system(RaspberryPI with Raspbian). Image was built on that same Raspberry.

This is my `dockerfile`:

```
FROM arm32v7/golang

COPY qemu-arm-static /usr/bin

ENV STATUSOK_VERSION 0.1.1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y unzip \
    && wget https://github.com/sanathp/statusok/releases/download/$STATUSOK_VERSION/statusok_linux.zip \
    && unzip statusok_linux.zip \
    && mv ./statusok_linux/statusok /go/bin/StatusOk \
    && rm -rf ./statusok_linux* \
    && apt-get remove -y unzip git \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

VOLUME /config
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT /docker-entrypoint.sh
```

I'm able to succesfully build this on a RaspberryPI running Raspbian:

```
root@raspberrypi:~/armstatusok# docker build . -t armstatusok
Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.656kB
Step 1/7 : FROM arm32v7/golang
 ---> 8bbfdfd01a06
Step 2/7 : COPY qemu-arm-static /usr/bin
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2572fd1e03a0
Step 3/7 : ENV STATUSOK_VERSION 0.1.1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 25d39a4c6eb5
Step 4/7 : RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y unzip     && wget https://github.com/sanathp/statusok/releases/download/$STATUSOK_VERSION/statusok_linux.zip     && unzip statusok_linux.zip     && mv ./statusok_linux/statusok /go/bin/StatusOk     && rm -rf ./statusok_linux*     && apt-get remove -y unzip git     && apt-get autoremove -y     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bfb1cfa9a985
Step 5/7 : VOLUME /config
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3bfbce28329b
Step 6/7 : COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a1795ca4f40c
Step 7/7 : ENTRYPOINT /docker-entrypoint.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d0ce74911ba3
Successfully built d0ce74911ba3
Successfully tagged armstatusok:latest
```

Next step is to run it, and where I get into trouble:

```
root@raspberrypi:~/armstatusok# docker run --name=armstatusok -v $PWD:/config armstatusok
/docker-entrypoint.sh: 1: /docker-entrypoint.sh: /go/bin/StatusOk: not found
```

I went into the container commenting line one of the `docker-entrypoint.sh` and checked if `/go/bin/StatusOk` was actually there, and it was.

My `docker-entrypoint.sh`:

```
root@raspberrypi:~/armstatusok# cat docker-entrypoint.sh
/go/bin/StatusOk --config /config/config.json
```

Now my question is, does anybody have a clue where to start? I also tested this dockerfile on x86 arch, and there it worked. I only changed the FROM line to the x86 flavour and removed the `COPY qemu-arm-static /usr/bin` since that line is there to make it work on ARM arch, according to documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I copied this Dockerfile and start script verbatim and it builds and runs perfectly for me. I get

`Config file not present at the given location:  /config/config.json give correct file location using --config parameter`

because I don't have access to the config file you're using. But the fact I get that message means that StatusOk is running. So I don't know what to suggest.

The only difference I made was to add a shebang `#!/bin/sh` to the start of the `docker-entrypoint.sh` file, and ensure it has execute permission, by running `ls -al`, and if it doesn't have `x` in the permissions, running `chmod +rwx`. Don't know if that made any difference as to how the script tried to access `/go/bin/StatusOk`.

[image]

Full `docker-entrypoint.sh` contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
/go/bin/StatusOk --config /config/config.json
```

Comment: Thank you very much for trying this at your own system. I tried it, again, with your remarks. I added the shebang and checked the permissions, but I still do get the same error. Now I'm looking for differences between your and my situation. I can only think of something ARCH or OS related. Some info: `Linux raspberrypi 4.14.71-v7+ #1145 SMP Fri Sep 21 15:38:35 BST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux`